# Rails (One Month Rails) NoMethodError in PinsController#create

Tags: methods, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems, associations

**Problem solved thanks to @skipchris (https://twitter.com/skipchris) Using debugger we found a spelling mistake. The error report didn't make much sense but i learned plenty investigating the problem!**

I've spent last night and this morning trying to find a solution but i'm new to rails. From what i've read so far it think the problem is to do with association. I created a Pin without a User (association error?) and so there is an error with routing i.e something to do with Devise?

When i try to create a new Pin i get this error in browser on my local server-

> NoMethodError in PinsController#create
>
> pp/controllers/pins_controller.rb:48:in `block in create'
>   app/controllers/pins_controller.rb:47:in`create'

pins_controller.rb

> def create
>
> @pin = current_user.pins.new(params[:pin])
>
> ```
> respond_to do |format|
>   if @pin.save
>     format.html { redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully created.' }
>     format.json { render json: @pin, status: :created, location: @pin }
>   else
>     format.html { render action: "new" }
>     format.json { render json: @pin.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> end

User Model (user.rb)

> class User < ActiveRecord::Base
>
> devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, #:recoverable, 
>            :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
>
> attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation,
>   :remember_me, :name
>
> has_many :pins
>
> end

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I would definitely make a user model since you are trying to access current_user.pins in the methods. also do you have

```
resources :pins
```

or something similar in your routes?

Comment: Hi Brandon. The defs are written as you've written. Copying from text editor and pasting to Stackoverflow must have changed the formatting.

Comment: So you don't have a user model? I would probably make one of those, even if it's simple... since you are trying current_user.pins

Comment: I have a user.rb in models. I'll add it to the question

Comment: Got "resources :pins" too

Comment: Thanks for the help Brandon but the problem solved thanks to @skipchris (https://twitter.com/skipchris) Using debugger we found a spelling mistake. The error report didn't make much sense but i learned plenty investigating the problem!

Comment: Great that you figured it out! Sorry I couldn't solve it, I'm at work now :).